# Why gdal.open(path).ReadAsArray() produce different results from tiffile.imread(path)

Tags: arrays, tiff, gdal

Since colab won't allow me to use tiffile.imread() by giving error 'ValueError: <COMPRESSION.LZW: 5> requires the 'imagecodecs' package', I use gdal.open().ReadAsArray() to read tif file and generate input data for model to inference. This results in:

[image]

When I use tiffile.imread() to read the same tif.file in another platform and created input with the same procedures as above. The model prediction finally goes to:

[image]

The results from the second image makes sense for the classes I want to predict. I just want to the reason that caused this difference. It seems gdal changed the order of pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally works for me. Since I cannot use tiffile.imread() in colab, I tried gdal and rasterio, but the image shape would be channel first. The problem for the first figure is caused by

```
np.reshape()
```

which did not change the axis of data dimension.
Then I used codes below and the issue is addressed.

```
with rio.open("gdrive/My Drive/file.tif") as ds:
  arr=ds.read()
np.moveaxis(arr, 0, -1)
```